# Vertx - Java - Using Handlers/lambda in a loop

Tags: java, asynchronous, functional-programming, vert.x

We have a list of srings which we loop through. In the loop we pass each string to a async call.

The problem is, the loop finishes and exits before all the asysnc calls are made.

```
public void processMessage(Handler<AsyncResult<List<String>>> handler){
    List<String> englishWords = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Hello","Where","How"));
    List<String> spanishWords = new ArrayList();
    for (int position = 0; position < englishWords.size(); position++) {
        getLocalisedMessageAsync(englishWords.get(position), resultHandler -> {
            if (resultHandler.succeeded()) {
                spanishWords.add(resultHandler.result());
            }
        });
    }
    handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(spanishWords));// this gets called before async calls
}
```

We solved this by using Promise object :

```
public void processMessage1(Handler<AsyncResult<List<String>>> handler){
    List<String> englishWords = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Hello","Where","How"));
    List<String> spanishWords = new ArrayList();
    Promise<List<String>> promise = Promise.promise();
    for (int position = 0; position < englishWords.size(); position++) {
        int finalPosition = position;
        getLocalisedMessageAsync(englishWords.get(position), resultHandler -> {
            if (resultHandler.succeeded()) {
                spanishWords.add(resultHandler.result());
                if (finalPosition == englishWords.size() - 1) {
                    promise.complete(spanishWords);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    promise.future().onComplete(completionHandler -> {
        if (completionHandler.succeeded()) {
            handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(spanishWords));
        }
    });
}
```

***But can there be a simplified solution to this? Where i can solve this without having to use Promise object***

Comment: one minor simplification could be using a map. `Map<String, String>` translation = new HashMap<>()`. You loop over the `englishWords` list and for every complete promise you put the translated word in the map. Like `translation.put(englishWord, spanishWord)`

Answer (score 2):

You could solve your task with CompletableFutures/CompletionStages.

Something like

```
private CompletionStage<ResultHandler> getLocalisedMessageRH(String englishWord) {
    CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    getLocalisedMessageAsync(englishWord, future::complete);
    return future;
}

private CompletionStage<String> getLocalisedMessageStage(String englishWord) {
    return getLocalisedMessageRH(englishWord)
        .thenApply(resultHandler -> {
            if (resultHandler.succeeded()) {
                return resultHandler.result();
            } else {
                throw <whatever unchecked exception>;
            }
        });
}

private CompletionStage<String> translate(CompletionStage<Void> base, String englishWord) {
    return base.thenCompose(dummy ->
        getLocalisedMessageStage(englishWord));
}

public void processMessage(Handler<AsyncResult<List<String>>> handler) {
    List<String> englishWords = new Arrays.asList("Hello", "Where", "How");
    List<String> spanishWords = new ArrayList();
    CompletionStage<Void> step = CompletableFuture.completedStage(null);
    for (int position = 0; position < englishWords.size(); position++) {
        step = translate(step, englishWords.get(position))
            .thenAccept(translation -> spanishWords.add(translation));
    }
    step
        .thenRun(() -> handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(spanishWords)))
        .exceptionally(exc -> { do whatever must be done});
}
```

This way, the CompletionStages are chained, and on a failure the chain is stopped till then (if this is what you want).